# How do I pass a variable from the azure resource manager json template to the CLI.

Tags: azure, docker, command-line-interface, devops, azure-resource-manager

I have a cli script that i am trying to turn into an arm template. I need to be able to pass a variable from the ARM template JSON variables object to the CLI so i can set environment variables so i can setup the database. Is there a way to accomplish this script within the arm template or a way to pass the variables from the Json template file?

```
#Variables
ACI_RANDOM=$RANDOM
ACI_APPNAME=jimfin$ACI_RANDOM
ACI_SUBSCRIPTION=Sandbox
ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP=$ACI_APPNAME
ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=$ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP$ACI_APPNAME
ACI_PERS_LOCATION=eastus
ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME=source
ACI_APP_SERVICE_PLAN=$ACI_APPNAME
ACI_SQL=database$ACI_APPNAME
ACI_FIREWALL=firewallrule$ACI_RANDOM
WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=$ACI_SQL.mysql.database.azure.com
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=My5up3rStr0ngPaSw0rd!
WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$WORDPRESS_DB_NAME@$ACI_SQL


#Bring in git repo 
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/cacorg/WPYAML-Files
cd WPYAML-Files

#Create APP SERVICE 
az group create --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --name $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --location "$ACI_PERS_LOCATION"
az appservice plan create --name $ACI_APP_SERVICE_PLAN --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --sku S1 --is-linux
az webapp create --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --plan $ACI_APP_SERVICE_PLAN --name $ACI_APPNAME --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-wordpress.yml

#PERSISTENT STORAGE
az webapp config appsettings set --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACI_APPNAME --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE

# Create Persistent sQL DB
az mysql server create --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACI_SQL  --location "$ACI_PERS_LOCATION" --admin-user $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME --admin-password $WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD --sku-name B_Gen4_1 --version 5.7
az mysql server firewall-rule create --name ACI_FIREWALL --server $ACI_SQL --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0
az mysql db create --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --server-name $ACI_SQL --name $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
az webapp config appsettings set --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACI_APPNAME --settings WORDPRESS_DB_HOST="$WORDPRESS_DB_HOST" WORDPRESS_DB_USER="$WORDPRESS_DB_USER" WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD="$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD" WORDPRESS_DB_NAME="$WORDPRESS_DB_NAME"

#UPDATE WEBAPP
az webapp config container set --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACI_APPNAME --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-wordpress.yml

#PERSISTENT STORAGE

az webapp config appsettings set --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACI_APPNAME --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE

az webapp config container set --subscription $ACI_SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACI_APPNAME --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose-wordpress.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, arm templates have outputs section, which you can use to return data as output from the template and then you can parse it:

```
az group deployment create -g name --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/master/azure-resource-manager/functions/intersection.json |
    jq '.properties.outputs.objectOutput.value'
```

you can save it to a variable and use it